# Error EWS The specified time zone isn't valid .net

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

im using EWS to send appointments to accounts of my corporation, developed on c# .net MVC 3.

**Code**

```
var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013,TimeZoneInfo.Local);
            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("myuser", "mypassowrd", "mycompany");
            service.TraceEnabled = true;
            service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
            service.Url = new Uri(uriString: "myexchangeserver" );
            TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific SA Standard Time");

            Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);

            appointment.Subject = "TestMeeting";
            appointment.Body = "The purpose of this meeting is to discuss status.";
            appointment.Start = new DateTime(2017, 12, 12, 9, 0, 0);
            appointment.End = appointment.Start.AddHours(2);
            appointment.Location = "Conf Room";
            appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add("myemail@mycompany.cl");
            appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);
```

and my problem is the following, when I execute the code until the final line, the next exception returns:

```
{"The specified time zone isn't valid."}
```

and I have not been able to find any solution, if you need more information, indicate in comments, thank you very much and sorry for my bad english :c

Answer (score 0):

This error has been reported as an issue in the EWS API on [github](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/issues/13).

However, it looks to be more likely an issue in .NET's `TimeZoneInfo` parsing logic. Updating your **.net** version might be the solution.

Here is an [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdav_101/2017/09/16/when-a-certain-time-zone-does-not-work-with-the-ews-managed-api/)  containing other possible solutions.

Comment: @Ariel Ignacio If this provided you with the solution then please mark it as the answer so as to help others viewing this question in the future